# Display Image from S3 with AWS Amplify in React-Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I cannot get my image to render. I upload a protected image to S3, no problem. I then use the below code to retrieve the image. When I log imageReturn I get the image URL with token.

```
state = {
    image: ''
}

async getImage(image) {
    let imageReturn = await Storage.get('9807139f-e5b4-428e-8dfb-d7cfeebe87ab.jpeg')
    this.setState({
        image: imageReturn
    })
}
```

I've tried rendering the image two different ways, with react-native's Image and with 'aws-amplify-react-native' S3Image.

```
<Image source={this.state.image} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}/>
```

and

```
<S3Image key={'9807139f-e5b4-428e-8dfb-d7cfeebe87ab.jpeg'} />
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does that image needs to be private ? or you have to showcase it on web and you can allow anyone to access it ?  then i can tell you how to get it like this [link]( https://s3.amazonaws.com/mausamrest/desk.JPG)

Comment: It needs to be visible by anyone but only editable by the person who uploads it.

Comment: What would you do if you have multiple images and want to select an image based upon which user is currently logged in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AWS get return image URL, Image URL printing Must be added *uri* .  Please Rewire Your code Snippest is

```
<Image source={uri:this.state.image} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}/>
```

Comment: This was the issue as well as needing to specify: Storage.configure({ level: 'protected' })